# Django: paginating differently on the first page

Tags: django, pagination

At the minute, I'm using Django's object_list to handle pagination. I'm happy to move to the proper Paginator() class if you think I need it after you hear my problem:

On the homepage, I want to paginate by **7**, but on *all other pages* I want to paginate by **10**.

How would I go about doing this? I really can't get my head around it. The closest I've got to making it work resulted in a whole page of results being left out, so obviously I don't want that.

I'd be extremely appreciative of any answers. Let me know if you need any more information. Thanks a lot.

Joe

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just `from django.core.paginator import Paginator` and make a paginator object as `p = Paginator(thestuff, 7)` in the view for the homepage, `p = Paginator(thestuff, 10)` everywhere else. Then in either case bind `p` in the context you use to render the template. `p.object_list` will be set appropriately in either case (and you appear to say that's the approach you're using, right? I.e., is that what you mean by "Django's object_list"?).

Django [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/topics/pagination/) have excellent details and examples (assuming you're on 1.0 or better). If you can't make it work, can you show us (a simplified version that still fails, of) your template and view code?

Edit: problem has now been clearly shown and I think should be solved by subclassing Django's core paginator, as follows:

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, Page

class MyPaginator(Paginator):

  def __init__(self, **kw):
    self.deltafirst = kw.pop('deltafirst', 0)
    Paginator.__init__(self, **kw)

  def page(self, number):
    "Returns a Page object for the given 1-based page number."
    number = self.validate_number(number)
    if number == 1:
      bottom = 0
      top = self.per_page - self.deltafirst
    else:
      bottom = (number - 1) * self.per_page - self.deltafirst
      top = bottom + self.per_page
    if top + self.orphans >= self.count:
      top = self.count
    return Page(self.object_list[bottom:top], number, self)
```

Now use MyPaginator exactly as the above text and examples show the usage of Django's own, except, on creating it, use an extra named argument `deltafirst=3` to make the first page 3 shorter than the normal per-page length (of 10). So you'd be using a single paginator with a nominal length of 10 but a deltafirst of 3 to make the first page 3 shorter than all others.

(There may be problems in `validate_number` but I'm not sure they'd appear -- if they do, then MyPaginator will need to override that method as well).

**Update for recent versions of Django**:

The above code would give an error due to not accounting the positional arguments and `num_pages` also needs to be overriden to allow the last pages to be shown properly:

```py
from math import ceil


class MyPaginator(Paginator):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        self.deltafirst = kw.pop('deltafirst', 0)
        super().__init__(*args, **kw)
    
    def page(self, number):
        number = self.validate_number(number)
        if number == 1:
            bottom = 0
            top = self.per_page - self.deltafirst
        else:
            bottom = (number - 1) * self.per_page - self.deltafirst
            top = bottom + self.per_page
        if top + self.orphans >= self.count:
            top = self.count
        return self._get_page(self.object_list[bottom:top], number, self)

    @property
    def num_pages(self):
        if self.count == 0 and not self.allow_empty_first_page:
            return 0
        count = max(self.count - self.per_page + self.deltafirst, 0)
        hits = max(0, count - self.orphans)
        return 1 + ceil(hits / self.per_page)
```

Comment: Hi Alex. Thanks for the suggestion, but there's a problem with it. If you have time, could you please look at http://pastie.org/527183, it shows what happens when I use a method similar to how you suggested. Basically, Django paginates by the right amount, but on page 2, it leaves the rows out that it thinks were shown on page 1 (even though they weren't as a different paginate_by amount was being used). Sorry, it's hard to explain, but it should make sense from the Pastie link. Anyone have a way to solve this?

Comment: Yep, saw the pastie link and it does make sense -- so I edited my answer to provide one solution (a tweaked subclass of Django 1.0's core Paginator).

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for taking the time to write that. Joe.

Answer (score 1):

The object_list() function uses the Paginator to break apart the list.
So, if you alter the "size" of the chunks (7 vs 8) ... then it does what you see.

**Choices:**
That last choice is wonky. Don't do that :-) Either "hack it" or move to the Paginator.

**Hack it** ... on requests > page 1, sneak something extra into the row_list. I'm guessing you could force it into a list via *list(row_list)*, and prepend a None or something via *row_list.insert(0, None)*

**Paginate** ... use the Paginator

**View + template** ... have your view just pass the queryset row_list to the template. Have the template check for page 1. Do you own looping/display of the subset of the row_list there. Its mucky to have such logic in your template. It makes for a complex template.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I tested the 'Hack It' method in Python shell and it worked well, so that definitely has the potential to solve this problem as well. Joe.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question but in case somebody, like me, comes here and find this my unittest discovered a problem.

Alex is essentially right but don't forget to also implement `_get_num_pages` with `self.orphans + self.deltafirst` otherwise the last page will not be correct.

```
def _get_num_pages(self):
    """Returns the total number of pages."""
    if self._num_pages is None:
        if self.count == 0 and not self.allow_empty_first_page:
            self._num_pages = 0
        else:
            hits = max(1, self.count - self.orphans + self.deltafirst)
            self._num_pages = int(ceil(hits / float(self.per_page)))
    return self._num_pages
num_pages = property(_get_num_pages)
```

And the unittest:

```
def test_ads_paginator(self):
    per_page = 10
    num_items = 100
    num_firstpage = 5
    expected_num_pages = 11

    items = range(num_items)
    paginator = AdsPaginator(items, per_page, deltafirst=per_page-num_firstpage)
    last_item = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages).object_list[-1]

    self.assertEqual(len(paginator.page(1)), num_firstpage)
    self.assertEqual(paginator.num_pages, expected_num_pages)
    self.assertEqual(last_item, items[-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

For my specific scenario, I was looking to paginate objects within 1 rendered template (creating a multi-page document). For my case, I think the easiest approach is to forget about paginator and use a generator instead.

```
    def pages_iter():
        page_num = 1
        num_records = lambda x: 30 if x > 1 else 10
        end_idx = 0

        while True:
            start_idx = end_idx
            end_idx += num_records(page_num)
            yield {
                'number': page_num,
                'object_list': donors[start_idx:end_idx]
            }

            if end_idx > donors.count() - 2:
                break
            page_num += 1
```

Add `{ pages: page_iter }` to your page context and then you have yourself a variable paginator. Note that `num_records` is a function that takes page_number, so you really have ultimate flexibility.

In your template, you can treat this just like you would paginator:

```
{% for page in pages %}
  {% if page.number == 1 %}
    {{ header }}
  {% endif %}

  {% for obj in page.object_list %}
    {{ obj }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```