# different number of records in django pagination pages

Tags: django

I'm trying to paginate with different things to maximize elements, on the first page (5) and on all the others (maximum 6).
I do like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054981/django-paginating-differently-on-the-first-page)

```
class MyPaginator(Paginator):

    def __init__(self, **kw):
        self.deltafirst = kw.pop('deltafirst', 0)
        Paginator.__init__(self, **kw)

    def page(self, number):
        number = self.validate_number(number)
        if number == 1:
            bottom = 0
            top = self.per_page - self.deltafirst
        else:
            bottom = (number - 1) * self.per_page - self.deltafirst
            top = bottom + self.per_page
        if top + self.orphans >= self.count:
            top = self.count
        return Page(self.object_list[bottom:top], number, self)


from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from django.core.paginator import EmptyPage
from django.core.paginator import PageNotAnInteger

class NewsView(ListView):
    model = News
    template_name="mysite/news.html"
    paginate_by =  5

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(NewsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs) 
        all_news = News.objects.all().order_by("-date_news")
        paginator = MyPaginator(all_news, self.paginate_by,deltafirst=1)

        page = self.request.GET.get('page')

        try:
            file_exams = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            file_exams = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            file_exams = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
        context['all_news'] = file_exams
        return context
```

But I get an error and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. The error itself

```
    paginator = MyPaginator(all_news, self.paginate_by,deltafirst=1)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly change your `__init__` method in `MyPaginator` to fix the error:

```py
from math import ceil


class MyPaginator(Paginator):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        self.deltafirst = kw.pop('deltafirst', 0)
        super().__init__(*args, **kw)
    
    def page(self, number):
        number = self.validate_number(number)
        if number == 1:
            bottom = 0
            top = self.per_page - self.deltafirst
        else:
            bottom = (number - 1) * self.per_page - self.deltafirst
            top = bottom + self.per_page
        if top + self.orphans >= self.count:
            top = self.count
        return Page(self.object_list[bottom:top], number, self)

    @property
    def num_pages(self):
        if self.count == 0 and not self.allow_empty_first_page:
            return 0
        count = max(self.count - self.per_page + self.deltafirst, 0)
        hits = max(0, count - self.orphans)
        return 1 + ceil(hits / self.per_page)
```

Next to make your view simpler instead of overriding `get_context_data` override `get_paginator` and also set `deltafirst` as a class attribute:

```py
class NewsView(ListView):
    model = News
    template_name="mysite/news.html"
    paginate_by =  5
    paginator_class = MyPaginator
    deltafirst = 1
    
    def get_paginator(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.deltafirst:
            kwargs['deltafirst'] = self.deltafirst
        return super().get_paginator(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: now i have this error `in get_paginator
    allow_empty_first_page=allow_empty_first_page, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given`

Comment: @ВадимШаройкин did you change the definition of the `__init__` method like so `def __init__(self, *args, **kw):` as I show in the answer? Note the addition of `*args,`. Also keep the rest of the code of the class i.e. the `page` method.

Comment: There is one more small question. if on 2 and following pages, less than 5 elements remain, they are not displayed?

Comment: @ВадимШаройкин what do you mean? Do you want that if some page has too few items those should be shown in the last page? Set `paginate_orphans = <number here>` in your `ListView` for that. If you set it to 2 and last page has only 2 items or less they would be shown in the previous page which would now be the last page.

Comment: With this code, if I have 7 news, then 5 is entered on the first, and the second page does not exist in pagination. It appears only if the remaining elements are 5 or more. And so on every next page if it has less than 5 news. In fact, the last page is displayed incorrectly

Comment: @ВадимШаройкин I see, actually the linked answer is a bit old. I have updated my answer and overriden the `num_pages` property to fix this problem.

Comment: It is a pity that you cannot put more than 1 plus for the answer. Thank you very much!